# rokoko addon missing re-targeting tab

Tags: rigging, add-on, bones

I had to download the rokoko plugin 1.1 as any newer version would not work for some reason. It would keep showing me error messages and wouldn't work at all. Trust me I've tried everything but only 1.1 managed to install. But now the re-targeting tab is missing??[image]

Comment: This Q&A site is run by volunteers and can only help with problems using Blender itself or its built-in addons. the Rokoko addon is a third-party addon, not part of Blender so you'll have to ask Rokoko that question. You do need to make sure that the addon version is compatible with the Blender version you're using first though.